# Android Studio 3.0 DexArchiveBuilderException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm having this error whilst compiling Instrumentation tests.

> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/SourceTree/Weather/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/androidTest/debug/1.jar
>
> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing org/assertj/core/api/LongPredicateAssert.class
>
> Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24

I tried to enable/disable `multiDexEnabled` in my `build.gradle` but nothing helped.

My `android` of `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.**.weather"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check into this? - `Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24` What do you have for your `min-sdk` check `build.gradle`

Comment: I'm updating my question

Comment: in `gradle.properties` add `android.enableD8=true`.

Comment: @Sunny could you add it as answer? That worked for me

Comment: @Sunny Nice answer! I wasn't even aware of their new D8 Compiler - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html

Comment: @RafaelRuiz I added the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In `gradle.properties` add `android.enableD8=true` This should work.

Please note that there is a known bug when you export and upload the apk to play store with d8 enable. The app will not run on some devices when downloaded from play store.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64740479

Comment: Well as I understand, problem is not with deploying apk to Play Store, it's rather about resulting app won't run on some devices. This is why they don't recommend publishing app compiled with D8

Comment: For those interested in knowing what android.enableD8 = true means, read here : 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html

Answer (score 5):

I just have the same error for me, it was because of okhttp and I downgrade implementation of it form:

to this:

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using guava, tou can try to upgrade it to the latest android-specific build

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'
```

This fixed the error for me when I was using the non-android guava build.

Answer (score 4):

With latest android studio 3.2 and gradle, we can also resolve it via

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' in app build.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and I resolved it by disabling the advanced profiling in run configuration.

Edit Configurations -> app -> Profiling -> Enable advanced profiling (Uncheck this option).

Answer (score -1):

add these line to your gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: then add these lines into your gradle : android.enableD8=true

Comment: gradle.properties