# How to handle DexArchiveBuilderException in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, selenium

I am trying to automate mobile applications using Appium and selenium and IDE is Android Studio.

But whenever I add Selenium standalone server jar file to lib folder of Android Studio I am getting `DexArchiveBuilderException`.

I couldn't able to figure it out.

Comment: may be solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137483/android-studio-3-0-dexarchivebuilderexception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 DexArchiveBuilderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137483/android-studio-3-0-dexarchivebuilderexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gradle.properties (it's in the root folder of your project) add `android.enableD8=true`

Comment: Thank you so much Serj Ardovic. It worked for me.

Comment: @Madhuri – on stackoverflow.com, if an answer helped you, make sure to mark it as a "correct answer"