# Error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

Tags: java, android, selenium, gradle, build.gradle

I am using Selenium in Java to make an app. I keep getting this error and I have been searching the internet to figure out what is wrong and I cannot find anything. Please help.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "luke.luke.seleniumtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar')
    implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.9.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guava-23.6-jre.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.9.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, try to add this line: exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', then Run 'app'

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
```

If error continue occur: 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST', keep adding exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST':

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}
```

Success for me!

Comment: This forced me to change my minsdk to 26. It also lead to: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Comment: I added youtube library then i was facing this issue. in my case second answer worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

The simple solution instead of excluding it is to just do

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst  'META-INF/*'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try add packagingOptions

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I get the error: Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/luke/AndroidStudioProjects/SeleniumTest/app/libs/client-combined-3.9.1.jar  Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing org/openqa/selenium/logging/LogCombiner.class.   Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)

Comment: what is your gradle version? and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137483/android-studio-3-0-dexarchivebuilderexception)

Comment: change minSdkVersion to 26

Comment: That will not work for my app. It will allow very few people to use it.

Comment: @LUKER did you find any solution, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @SajidZeb I did not, have you yet?