# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 114237 > 65536)

Tags: android, api, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to import [this](https://github.com/ShimmerEngineering/ShimmerAndroidAPI/tree/master/ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver) driver to my simple app (at the moment just only the default text view)  in android 3.5 version. The driver library was installed and wanted to run the emulator and I encountered several Gradle issues and was able to fix them and finally ended up here.  When I entered,

> classpath 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

in the Gradle.

though the build successful, when I run the app I received the build error as mentioned below.

> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 114237 > 65536)

Further, I'm not sure where to put (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex))

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958884/error-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-dependenc)) ,

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```

since my build.gradle is as below,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/shimmerengineering/Shimmer"
        }

    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    classpath 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/shimmerengineering/Shimmer"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

~ Thank you ~

---

Fixed as below :

Created a new test application and found the build.gradle file and included

`allprojects { repositories { jcenter() maven { url "dl.bintray.com/shimmerengineering/Shimmer" } } }`

then the arrived issues were fixed as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958884/error-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-dependenc). Then when running the emulator there were no build or any other issues.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong `build.gradle` file. The things that you cited need to be added to the `build.gradle` file for your module (e.g., `app/build.gradle`).

Comment: Oh ! well I have now created a new test application and found the build.Gradle file and included 'allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://dl.bintray.com/shimmerengineering/Shimmer"
        }
    }
}'

Comment: Then again faced the same issues as in  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958884/error-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-dependenc) and as in this [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex. I was able to fix the issues. And emulator worked with text view !!! Hopefully, I can continue now !!! Thank you for the support !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try making maximum hip size to 4 Gigabyte in app level gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"//this line
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the guide, but this didn't work for me. I have changed the Gradle file now and then it worked after some fixes of the issues.