# Only on androidTest: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

My codebase makes use of some Java 8 syntax like lambdas and has been working fine for the longest time.

Recently, my instrumented tests in a module stopped working with the infamous message:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported
>   starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

This is a known problem (there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812717/error-invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-o-min-api-26) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891730/invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-0-min-api-26) referencing it), but I have Java 1.8 in my `compileOptions`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

This problem ONLY shows up in the instrumented tests (i.e. androidTest). It's fine with unit tests and with the app itself. I already commented out all tests from the instrumented tests, but the problem persists.

My unit tests and Android tests have the same dependencies. I converted to AndroidX tests, but the issue persists.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0'    
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'    
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
}
```

I'm using the latest compile and target versions (I also tried 26 and 27) and also build tools. The min SDK version is 14, and should be.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '29.0.0 rc3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
}
```

Comment: It's a little odd that your `buildToolsVersion` doesn't match your `compileSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion`... any chance that's the culprit?

Comment: @BenP. Not really, I'm using the beta version of Android Studio. I tried older build tools as well though (version ~28), with the same result.

Comment: So I narrowed it down to the build tools of the application itself - 3.4.0 works fine, 3.5.0-beta01 not so much. Apparently a bug in Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: @EboMike have you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Studio 3.5 beta. I filed a [bug with the Android Studio team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132695131), and this will be fixed with the Android Studio 3.5 beta 03 build tools.

Comment: i think it's not fixed yet.

Comment: i still have problem with AS 3.5.3 and build tools 29.0.2

Comment: I have the issue in Android studio 4.0.1

Comment: I still have the issue with AS 4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When Project and Clean Project run again. the problem with me was in his org.apache.commons: commons-text:library.
Change
implementation 'org.apache.commons: commons-text: 1.8'
To
implementation 'org.apache.commons: commons-text: 1.6'

Answer (score -2):

Update your root build.gradle to use latest android sdk(you can use 26 or 28).

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: I am using the latest SDK, but my minSdkVersion is (and should be) 14.